# Firebase Serve command failing with error 404

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Whenever I run firebase serve on my mac I am getting a 404 error...This has never happened before and I was just using the local dev server maybe 5 minutes before this started happening. I have deleted the firebase.json file and reinitialized it, reinstalled firebase tools but it fails every time. Here are the results from running the command in debug mode.

```
    firebase serve --debug
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.873Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.876Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase serve --debug
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.877Z] CLI Version:   4.2.1
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.877Z] Platform:      darwin
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.877Z] Node Version:  v6.11.3
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.878Z] Time:          Tue Sep 11 2018 11:12:25 GMT-0500 (CDT)
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.878Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-09-11T16:12:25.890Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.890Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2018-09-11T16:12:25.893Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/skadaddle-10f24  

[2018-09-11T16:12:26.210Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:12:26 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=114, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
[2018-09-11T16:12:26.212Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/skadaddle-10f24  

[2018-09-11T16:12:26.385Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:12:26 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35", accept-ranges=none, connection=close

=== Serving from '/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Source/Skadaddle'...

[2018-09-11T16:12:26.388Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/255074367563/clients/_:getWebAppConfig  

[2018-09-11T16:12:26.514Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 404 vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, date=Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:12:26 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35", accept-ranges=none, connection=close
[2018-09-11T16:12:26.514Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY code=404, message=Requested entity was not found., status=NOT_FOUND

Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found.
[2018-09-11T16:12:26.519Z] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 404,
      "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
      "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "body": {
      "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "vary": "X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "date": "Tue, 11 Sep 2018 16:12:26 GMT",
      "server": "ESF",
      "cache-control": "private",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "alt-svc": "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39,35\"",
      "accept-ranges": "none",
      "connection": "close"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/v1/projects/255074367563/clients/_:getWebAppConfig",
        "path": "/v1/projects/255074367563/clients/_:getWebAppConfig",
        "href": "https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/v1/projects/255074367563/clients/_:getWebAppConfig"
      },
      "method": "GET"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue. For me, functions work, but hosting does not. Edit: functions start, I have not actually attempted to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with Google. When you run `firebase serve` it makes a request to https://mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com which is currently throwing a 404 error.

I was able to get around this (temporary fix) by editing 3 files in `node_modules/firebase-tools/lib`.

On line 99 of `api.js` is where the bad URL is being called. Simply change that to any valid non-404ing url.

Then, in `fetchWebSetup.js`, change the parameter on line 9 after `"GET"` to a blank string (e.g. `return api.request("GET", "", {`

Do that same as above to `functionsConfig.js` on line 51.

This should get you up and running for now, but this should resolve itsself when Google fixes that URL.

Answer (score 16):

*Firebase employee here*

There is a known problem with CLI deployment.  It's being investigated.  You can track the outage here:

https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/18015

Whenever you experience a CLI failure like this, please contact Firebase support directly, with all the relevant details:

https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does it have to fetch those URLs each time we firebase serve?

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing every time.

Comment: I am getting this error as of today, has this reappeared as an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I could only fix this issue by deleting `.firebaserc` and then running `firebase init` again. Only make sure that you won't override existing configuration by mistake.